# How can I iterate through a list of XML files using Python and append certain fields?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Essentially I have a series of XML files in PASCALVOC format but the annotations are wrong, and are off by a factor of 10. I need to iterate through the files and essentially add a '0' to specific fields (xmax, xmin, ymax, etc.).
The XML files all look like this:

```
<folder>VOC2014</folder>
<filename>2014_000001.png</filename>
<source>
    <database>PASCAL VOC Compatible Annotation Database</database>
    <annotation>Department of Electrical Engineering</annotation>
    <image>PASCAL</image>
</source>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>car</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmax>592</xmax>
        <xmin>183</xmin>
        <ymax>338</ymax>
        <ymin>1</ymin>
    </bndbox>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occluded>1</occluded>
    <pose>Frontal</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
</object>
<size>
    <depth>1</depth>
    <height>400</height>
    <width>600</width>
</size>
```

Whereas in this scenario I want xmax to be appended to 5920, xmin to be appended to 1830. The ElementTree module seems promising but I'm having trouble with the Find and Replace functions across multiple files. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you get error message? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first write function for single file - `def process(filename)` - and later run it in `for`-loop with list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample xml is not well formed (it needs to wrapped in a root element), but assuming that is fixed you can try something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

bnd = """your xml above, fixed"""

doc = ET.fromstring(dnd)
for d in doc.findall('.//object/bndbox'):
    for line in d.findall('*'):
        line.text= str(int(line.text)*10)
print(ET.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should have all `<bndbox>` child nodes with a value equal to 10 times the original.